# How to recover from broken PVMOVE transfer?

Tags: linux

I made the mistake of not using `screen` while doing a `pvmove`.

I am copying data from one SAN to another using `pvmove`. The network died in the middle of a `pvmove` and now I have one `pv` with part of the data and another with the other half. When I try to start a new `pvmove` it says there is not enough free space in the destination `pv`. What is the best way to move the remaining data to a new `pv`?

Comment: The move will automatically resume the next time the volume is activated with both pvs present.

Answer (score 4):

first check what is the current status:

```
lvs -a -o +devices
```

If you see that it is actually in the middle (LVs not residing on both old and new PVs with temporary name), follow the command with no arguments:

```
pvmove 
/dev/md1: Moved: 99.0%
/dev/md1: Moved: 99.1%
/dev/md1: Moved: 99.2%
 ...
/dev/md1: Moved: 99.8%
/dev/md1: Moved: 99.9%
/dev/md1: Moved: 100.0%
```

From the manual:

> If pvmove gets interrupted for any reason (e.g. the machine crashes) then run pvmove again without any PhysicalVolume arguments to restart any moves that were in progress from the last checkpoint. Alternatively use pvmove --abort at any time to abort them at the last checkpoint.